# Copy a file from BDL to ADLS

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need to copy a file from BDL(business data lake) to ADLS. Then split it into 5 files in ADLS based on a condition.

I am new to Azure databricks, need suggestion how I can do this.

Comment: hi @Nilesh Patel, could you please provide ADLS condition.

Answer (score 0):

**Copy a file from Datalake to ADLS. Please follow below approach .**

Using this code you can copy data from Datalake to ADLS

```
spark.conf.set(
    "fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
    "<your-storage-account-access-key>")

dbutils.fs.cp("abfss://<container>@<stoarge_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<folder>/<subfolder>*','abfss://mycontainer@mydatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/')
```

**Or**

```
dbutils.fs.mv("dbfs:/tmp/test/**", "dbfs:/tmp/<folder_name>")
```